# How do I set IrfanView as my scan handler?

Tags: windows-7, scanner, irfanview

I want to configure my scanner so that I can just push the button on the printer and have it open IrfanView for me ready to scan.

I know that I can configure my printer's scan events by right clicking on the printer and going to "Scan properties," but the only program that appears on the list of events (Scan to File, Scan to E-mail, Scan to OCR, and Scan to Image) is Corel PhotoImpact, beside the default Windows scan programs.

How can I get IrfanView to appear on the programs list so that I can add it as a handler and have it automatically open the scanner menu?

Comment: I'm not sure you can... IrfanView doesn't handle scanning itself, it just calls Twain, WIA, or other scan utility to import an image.

Comment: @acejavelin Neither does PhotoImpact. They are just front ends to these interfaces.

Comment: the photo program is probably registered with the system as handling/opening/editing specific picture/image extentions.  See if there exists an "associations" in the options of the irfanview, xnview has it. you could also search the registry for the photo programs exe , and see what it is associated with.  The selection of programs for other scanners i have seen, are based on programs that have tossed things into the registry on install, not portablised. Possibly tied with the "open with" , so you could view there in the context menu how various pictures will use that also.

Comment: chances are good that if they both show in the "open with" for specific pics like bmps and jpegs, they may also open in the scanner requester for a place that they can be sent to.  so open with irfanview, and see if that sets it.

Comment: @Psycogeek IrfanView is already in the open with menu. But the problem is that scanning is actually a hidden AutoPlay handler rather than a file association.